# How To Remove/Add Windows Options from Boot Loader

Tags: ubuntu, windows-vista, multi-boot, grub

I am having windows vista and ubuntu operation system on my laptop . I  just want to remove that option from my boot loader ( grub )  and i need to know how add back that option.  I would like to Do the following Operations

1. Need To Remove Boot option for windows ( which is listing on Booting list ) on grub
2. Add it later after  some time again
3. Change the booting Order and change the default booting option too..

Comment: listing the Booting option like ubantu , windows loader

Comment: It's not clear what you want to do - do you want to replace the Grub bootloader with the Windows bootloader, or do you want to add additional entries (e.g. for booting to your Windows installation) to the Grub bootloader?

Comment: I just want the windows booting item from grub and replacing again some time later

Comment: Oh, and by the way, _why_ do you want to remove it if you'll need to enter it back later? Maybe you just need to change boot order?

Comment: i have edited the question

Comment: I suggest not removing it, instead just change the default alternative and lower the time limit.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To edit grub boot menu just go to console and type in

> gksudo gedit /boot/grub/menu.lst

enter your password, and remove all records corresponding to Vista. To add that option back later, just re-enter those lines. Or backup that menu.lst file before making any changes, like this:

> sudo cp /boot/grub/menu.lst /boot/grub/menu.lst.backup

and restore from it later.

You can find more info about boot options in [Community Ubuntu documentation](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/BootOptions), in the [Change Boot Options Permanently On An Existing Installation](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/BootOptions#Change%20Boot%20Options%20Permanently%20On%20An%20Existing%20Installation) section.

ED: If you just want to remove it for convenience, so that Ubuntu would always boot first, then you would be better off just changing the boot order. To do that start editing menu.lst like was shown previously. Find the line containing *default #* (where # is some number, 0 by default) and change # to the number of your desired operating system in the boot list. You can also change how long boot menu will be displayed. Just find the line containing *timeout #* (where # is some number, 10 by default) and change it to the desired time in seconds.